# ggplot2 - how to create a clustered timeline?

Tags: r, ggplot2

How would you go about creating the graph below in R?  I want to show the duration of different treatments for different patients.

[image: Clustered Timeline]

Mock data here:

```
                       Start Day    Stop Day
Patient 1   Drug 1     1            3
            Drug 2     2            5
            Drug 3     3            8
Patient 2   Drug 1     2            4
            Drug 2     2            5
            Drug 3     1            6
Patient 3   Drug 1     4            7
            Drug 2     3            8
            Drug 3     5            6
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your graph can be generated using `geom_segment` in the `ggplot2` package:

```
df <- structure(list(Patient = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Patient1", "Patient2", "Patient3"), class = "factor"), 
    Drug = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("Drug1", 
    "Drug2", "Drug3"), class = "factor"), StartDay = c(1L, 2L, 
    3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 5L), StopDay = c(3L, 5L, 8L, 4L, 
    5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 6L)), .Names = c("Patient", "Drug", "StartDay", 
"StopDay"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))

df$Drug <- factor(df$Drug, levels(df$Drug)[c(3,2,1)])

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=df, aes(color=Drug))+
      geom_segment(aes(x=StartDay, xend=StopDay, y=Drug, yend=Drug),lwd=12)+
      facet_grid(Patient~.)+xlab("Days")
```

[image]